# What will happen when I disable a timer?

Tags: vb.net

I am confused what will happen, when I disable a timer. Will it finish the process and then disable or will it immediately disable without completing process?

for example

```
Private Sub MyTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyTimer.Tick 
    MyTimer.Enabled = False
    getMessage()         
    MyTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I want to run getMessage from somewhere else, so I need to disable timer during that time  to be asured not to override anything and also before timer disable it should complete that function code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled.aspx) MSDN article about the `Timer`'s `Enabled` property. It states

> Calling the Start method is the same as setting Enabled to true. Likewise, calling the Stop method is the same as setting Enabled to false.

So in answer to your question, it will stop the `Timer` when you disable it.

Comment: Suppose this function taking 5 min. to complete now suppose i disable the timer so whether this function will going to finish or not?

Comment: If you mean the function that's handling the `Timer.Tick` event, then yes it will, but it won't be called again until you re-start the `Timer`. The `getMessage()` function will also finish as it is completely independent of the `Timer`.

Answer (score 1):

The Enabled Property just controls when the next event will be fired. The three lines above will do what you explain: call getMessage and start the Timer after the call returns.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is currently executing `MyTimer_Tick` and you disable the timer it will of course finish `MyTimer_Tick`. Only the next call to `MyTimer_Tick` is not going to happen.
After disabling your timer you will have to wait in case your callback is currently executing. You can do busy waiting using `Thread.Sleep()` or use an `AutoResetEvent`.